# Is it legal for U.S. based websites to serve online gambling ads?

Tags: advertising, legal

I have a site that hits the sweet spot for that demographic but my user base is 90% in the U.S.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like it is okay to do for now but is still a grey area. Here's a good article that goes into detail about this:

[Advertising Online Casinos - An Analysis of the Legal Rights and Risks](http://www.firstamendment.com/site-articles/advertising-casinos/)

Excerpt:

> While the legality of online gaming
>   itself is still an open question as a
>   result of conflicting court decisions
>   and stalled legislation, the legal
>   issues relating to advertising online
>   gambling services are even more
>   obscure. One of the reasons is that
>   the power of the government to
>   regulate advertising of a particular
>   product or service is not coextensive
>   with its ability to regulate or ban
>   the same product or service.

and

> The concept of Internet gaming
>   advertising raises a host of legal
>   issues that are dependant on a number
>   of factors, including the medium
>   chosen for the promotion and the
>   potential applicability of various
>   state and/or federal laws. The courts
>   will employ the same legal analysis
>   used to evaluate traditional gambling
>   advertising regulations, but under a
>   relatively new paradigm that is based
>   on the underlying premise that the
>   government’s power to prohibit or
>   regulate particular conduct does not
>   necessarily include the power to
>   prohibit or regulate speech about that
>   conduct.57 The traditional
>   justifications for imposing
>   restrictions on gambling advertising
>   may well be lacking in the context of
>   online gambling promotion. Virtual
>   casinos do not generate increased
>   prostitution or drug activity, and
>   have not been historically infiltrated
>   by organized crime. The inability to
>   effectively geographically limit the
>   target audience for online gambling
>   advertising may also impair the
>   government’s ability to
>   constitutionally restrict advertising
>   about online gaming services to areas
>   where it is considered a legal
>   activity. Thus far, the United States
>   government has not specifically
>   legislated in the area of Internet
>   gambling, let alone the advertising of
>   such services. While the various
>   states have touched on this subject,
>   or have enacted legislation which
>   appears to regulate or prohibit such
>   promotions, the validity of any such
>   laws as applied to virtual casinos is
>   questionable.

Answer (score 1):

If speaking about Google Adwords, it supports responsible gambling advertising with the condition that it meets the Gambling ads standards.
https://support.google.com/adspolicy/answer/6008942?visit_id=636842806628138245-446114262&rd=1